# ec2 ssh login Permission Denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Unlike any other questions, suddenly I was not able to login ec2 through ssh. I have logged in 2 mins before I got this error.

```
ssh -i keypair.pem ec2-user@[erastic ip]
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I checked:

> 1. keypair. I have one keypair and there is no way to miss take. Also, done "chmod 600 keypair.pem"
> 2. ec2-user. I also tested ec2-user, root and other users.
> 3. Instance reboot.

Thank you

Comment: Did you change anything in the file system prior to this happening? Also, try to telnet to the server providing port 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Seems chmod 700 at root disables re-access.

1. Detach the volume from the instance.
2. Create a temp instance.
3. Attach the detached volume to the temp instance.
4. chmod
5. Re-attach the volume to the instance.

Don't chmod 700 at root.